# how to get filter httpservletresponse outputstream error message in filter

Tags: servlets, spring-security

I am using spring 4 and filters I got some error response in servletResponse. It contains outputstream with an error message.
How can I get this error message in Outputstream and audit to my app?

```
try{            
            filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, servletResponse);
            HttpServletResponse  httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            LOGGER.info("Basic Authenticate HttpServletResponse code {}"+httpServletResponse.getStatus());

            httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
// I need to read this outputstream, its contains error message.?




    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("Error Basic Authenticate Error :{}", e);
        HttpServletResponse  httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        AtomicInteger statusCode = new AtomicInteger(httpServletResponse.getStatus());
        Response response = ResponseUtil.populateResponse(statusCode, e.getMessage().toString(), 0);
        httpServletResponse.sendError(httpServletResponse.getStatus(), e.getMessage());
        auditService.updateRestAuditRecord(auditId,StringUtils.EMPTY, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is the `HttpServletResponseWrapper` decorator class. Adapt these steps to your specific needs:

1. Fully read the stream you want to audit to something like a byte buffer.
2. Do your auditing task.
3. Extend `HttpServletResponseWrapper`, override `getOutputStream()` and return an extension of `ServletOutputStream` that streams your byte buffer.
4. Pass the `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to the next downstream filter in the chain.

Comment: Ok I will try.. Thanks

Comment: I am try this below code, byteArr is empty.

      
1. HtmlResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HtmlResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);
  
2. ServletOutputStream sout = responseWrapper.getOutputStream();
   ByteArrayOutputStream capture = new 3. ByteArrayOutputStream(responseWrapper.getBufferSize());
   capture.writeTo(sout);
   sout.flush();
   sout.close();
   
   byte[] byteArr = capture.toByteArray();